# Square API - cash-drawer-shift unauthorized?

Tags: square, square-connect

I've been using the Square v1 API https://connect.squareup.com/v1/{{location_id}}/cash-drawer-shifts/ to get a list of recent cash drawer open/closes.  This stopped working last weekend.  I now receive a 401- unauthorized error.  Has something changed?  Is there a similar call in the v2 API?

Comment: We are looking into a potential issue with that endpoint at this time, but there is not an analogous v2 endpoint to use as a replacement. Thank you for reporting your problems!

Comment: this should be working normally now.

Comment: Working again!  Thank you :)